# Deadly Chill cold damage

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats

The feat deadly chill from Libris Mortis (p.25) reads:

> Each corporeal undead you raise or create with any necromancy spell deals an extra 1d6 points of cold damage with its natural weapons.

Would a skeleton with 2 claw and 1 bite attack thus deal an extra 1d6 on each attack? (Claw x2 and Bite x1) for a total of 3 extra d6 of cold damage, or does this only apply to one attack?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## All of 'em!

*Libris Mortis* contains no further information on the feat **Deadly Chill**  (25–6), but the feat's benefit does *not* say, for example, "The corporeal undead creature's creator picks one of the undead creature's natural weapons, and that natural weapon deals this extra +1d6 points of cold damage," or anything like that, so this DM would have each natural attacks of an appropriate undead creature deal that extra +1d6 points of cold damage.